# get the steam market lowest prices?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, steam

I search the stackoverflow.com for my issue,and i found this answer related to mine.the problem is i dont know how to apply this code to my asp.net mvc web site

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20|%20Vulcan%20%28Battle-Scarred%29');
$attrList = explode('<span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">',$string);
$N=count($attrList);
for ($i=1;$i<$N;$i++){
    $prices[$i-1] = explode('</span>',$attrList[$i])[0];
}
print_r($prices);
?>
```

Comment: You want to apply PHP code to an ASP.NET website?

Comment: yes,I want this work on asp.net website @TZHX

Comment: Do you understand the PHP code?

Comment: No,I am newbie to coding @TZHX

Comment: Then go read a tutorial on ASP.NET MVC. Stack Overflow is not for helping you learn to program, but to solve specific programming issues. "How to perform an HTTP request, parse HTML and get meaningful values out of it" is not specific, that's too broad instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var pageAsString = wc.DownloadString(new Uri("http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20|%20Vulcan%20%28Battle-Scarred%29"));

var attrList = pageAsString.Split(new string[] { "<span class=\"market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee\">"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var prices = new List<string>();

for (var i = 1; i < attrList.Count(); i++)
{
    prices.Add(attrList[i].Split(new string[] { "</span>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault().Trim());
}

// Do something with prices variable
```

Comment: thx i will try this to something with this,it is more meaningful for me,it seems like a <script>